# ES2015 "import" not working in node v6.0.0 with with --harmony_modules option

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am using node v6.0.0 and wanted to use ES2016 (ES6). However I realized that the "import" syntax is not working. Isn't "import" fundamental to for writing modular code in ES2015? I tried running node with `--harmony_modules` option as well but still got the same error about "import". Here's the code.

Working code without "import":

```
'use strict';
let sum = 0;
class Number {

  addNumber(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  }
}
let numberObj = new Number();
sum = numberObj.addNumber(1,2);
console.log("sum of two number 1 and 2 "+ sum);
```

Notworking code with "import":

server.js

```
'use strict';
import Number from "./Number";

let sum = 0;


let numberObj = new Number();

sum = numberObj.addNumber(1,2);
console.log("sum of two number 1 and 2 "+ sum);
```

Number.js

```
'use strict';
export default class Number {

  addNumber(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
  }
}
```

I also checked http://node.green/ to see the supported es6 however not able to understand why it doesn't work with --harmony_modules option. Please help.

Comment: use Webpack together Babel loader

Comment: You should not need babel or webpack in v6

Comment: This [Nodesource article explains why modules aren't implemented yet](https://nodesource.com/blog/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices/).

Comment: related SO question: [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37132668/245966)

Comment: See also [this blog post](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e) from Sep 2016 explaining challenges in implementing ES6 `import` in node. It seems we're still a long way before ES6 modules ship in node.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

They're just not implemented yet.

Node 6.0.0 uses a version of V8 with most of ES6 features completed. Unfortunately modules isn't one of those completed features.

```
node --v8-options | grep harmony
```

**in progress** harmony flags are not fully implemented and usually are not working:

--es_staging (enable test-worthy harmony features (**for internal use only**))
  --harmony (enable all completed harmony features)
  --harmony_shipping (enable all shipped harmony features)
  --harmony_object_observe (enable "harmony Object.observe" (**in progress**))
  **--harmony_modules** (enable "harmony modules" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_function_sent (enable "harmony function.sent" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_sharedarraybuffer (enable "harmony sharedarraybuffer" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_simd (enable "harmony simd" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_do_expressions (enable "harmony do-expressions" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_iterator_close (enable "harmony iterator finalization" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_tailcalls (enable "harmony tail calls" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_object_values_entries (enable "harmony Object.values / Object.entries" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_object_own_property_descriptors (enable "harmony Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors()" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_regexp_property (enable "harmony unicode regexp property classes" (**in progress**))
  --harmony_function_name (enable "harmony Function name inference")
  --harmony_regexp_lookbehind (enable "harmony regexp lookbehind")
  --harmony_species (enable "harmony Symbol.species")
  --harmony_instanceof (enable "harmony instanceof support")
  --harmony_default_parameters (enable "harmony default parameters")
  --harmony_destructuring_assignment (enable "harmony destructuring assignment")
  --harmony_destructuring_bind (enable "harmony destructuring bind")
  --harmony_tostring (enable "harmony toString")
  --harmony_regexps (enable "harmony regular expression extensions")
  --harmony_unicode_regexps (enable "harmony unicode regexps")
  --harmony_sloppy (enable "harmony features in sloppy mode")
  --harmony_sloppy_let (enable "harmony let in sloppy mode")
  --harmony_sloppy_function (enable "harmony sloppy function block scoping")
  --harmony_proxies (enable "harmony proxies")
  --harmony_reflect (enable "harmony Reflect API")
  --harmony_regexp_subclass (enable "harmony regexp subclassing")

Comment: Thanks. I saw it but was not believing myself as "import" is one of the important syntax of es6

Comment: @joy Yeah, hopefully it's available soon.

Comment: Thanks. where can i find the in progress list?

Comment: @KingWu I just found it by running `node --v8-options | grep harmony` after updating to `node 6.0.0`.

Comment: Is there any place where we can check the plans to integrate this option? Maybe for node 7?

Comment: Here is a relevant bug to watch: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569

Comment: I was so glad to hear node 6 was out, and now they didn't implement one of the most important features ... :(

Comment: @Mr.Goferito et all, you can see what is and what isn't implemented here: http://node.green/

Comment: @SuperUberDuper Use Node 7

Comment: @AliGajani I've got node v8.1.3 and still the same problem.

Comment: This article from Feb 10 2017 says it'll be *at least* a year: https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c  So maybe mid-2018?

Answer (score 41):

This should be a comment to @Paulpro's answer but I do not have enough rep to post a comment.

For **Windows** users the equivalent command is:

```
node --v8-options | findstr harmony
```

Answer (score 32):

Until modules are implemented you can use [the Babel "transpiler"](https://babeljs.io) to run your code:

```
npm install --save babel-cli babel-preset-node6
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets node6 ./your_script.js
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node6 and https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

**Downsides**: this has various downsides, such as extra compilation time, which can be significant and you now need source maps for debugging; just saying.

Answer (score 16):

As is stated above, ES6 modules are not implemented yet.

It appears to be a non-trivial issue to implement ES6 modules in a way that would be backward-compatible with Common JS modules, which is the current Node.js module syntax.

However, there is a [draft](https://github.com/nodejs/node-eps/blob/master/002-es6-modules.md) of an implementation, that introduces a new file extension - `.mjs` - for  a files containing ES6 modules.

Also, there is a [counter-proposal](https://github.com/dherman/defense-of-dot-js/blob/master/proposal.md) that present an alternative approach of declaring all files with ES6 modules in package.json like so:

```
{
    "modules.root": "/path/to/es6/modules"
}
```

Comment: I think this is an important point. "The Powers That Be" are still arguing about the spec, and then it has to appear in v8 before it can get to Node.

Comment: Just a note: The newest draft does not require `.mjs` as an extension, which is much better for compatibility.

Comment: Question is : where can I find these es6 modules to download ?

Comment: This [blog post](http://2ality.com/2017/09/native-esm-node.html) may be a good place to start.