# ES6 import and export are not supported in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I'm building a project using WebStorm 2016.2.2. I use version 6.6.0 of Node.js. I have set the JavaScript version to ES6, but I get "unexpected token" errors for both `import` and `export` keywords. I don't get errors for Lambda expressions BTW.

Why do I get this error? Am I doing something wrong or Node just does not support `import` and `export` without Babel (even though I have set the JavaScript version to ES6)?

Comment: can you post an excerpt of the code, please?

Comment: `I get "unexpected token" errors for both "import" and "export" keywords` this sounds like ESLint complaining, not Node.js. You have to enable import/export separately, as enabling ES6 enables anything _but_ them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js supports CommonJS modules, however support for ECMAScript modules is [currently being designed](https://hackernoon.com/node-js-tc-39-and-modules-a1118aecf95e#.syckycenu).

In the meantime, you'll have to use Babel to transform ECMAScript modules to CommonJS. Try using a minimal preset for Node.js builds, like [`babel-preset-node6`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node6).

Answer (score 4):

es6 does support import and export, node 6 does not support es6 import/export up till now as far as I know.

This question can be helpful: [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules)