# Treat self as a node module for npm

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a javascript project which is released as a node module. For some reasons, I have some source code using relative paths to import other files in this project:

```
// <this_module_path>/action/foo.js
import execution from './execution';
import types from '../types';
```

and also **using a module name as a root path** to import other files in this project:

```
// <this_module_path>/action/doSomething.js
// Using module name to import

// equals to import './helpers.js' in this case (in the same folder)
import executionHelpers from 'this-module/action/helpers.js';
// equals to import '../types/helpers' in this case
import typeHelpers from 'this-module/types/helpers.js';
```

How can I have a such file to import other project files using its module name rather than relative paths?

Comment: Are you using Babel to transpile your code to convert `import` syntax to CommonJS?

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS uses [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) to import javascript moduels. There is [no clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132668/177006) timeline for adding ES6 `import / export` syntax to NodeJS. So you need to transpile your code using Babel to CommonJS module system before you can run it on NodeJS.

## How to do this using CommonJS

1. Create a separate package for your `this-module` module. The package needs to be created inside `node_modules` directory of your main module. You can do this using `npm init` command inside the `node_modules` directory.
2. Inside that file, you need to create a Javascript file (conventionally called `index.js` and make it the main script of that package.

Your `package.json` should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
}
```

3. In the `index.js` you can export your variables (such as `helpers` and `types`) and you can easily import them in your main package.