# Can you import node's path module using import path from 'path'

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I prefer using the `import x from 'y'` syntax, but all I've seen online is `const path = require('path')`.

Is there a way to import the path module using this syntax?

Comment: What transpiler are you using? Have you tried it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules)

Answer (score 281):

**For people trying to import `path` in a TypeScript file, and ending up here:**

1. Be sure to have node types installed:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @types/node
   ```
2. Import path symbol:

   ```
   import * as path from 'path';
   ```

Note: `@types/*` are automatically included for compilation, providing you use typescript version 2.0 or above, and provided you don't override the `types` property in compiler options file (*tsconfig.json*).

Comment: In my case, besides doing `npm install --save-dev @types/node`, I also had to update my `tsconfig.json` and add `node` under `compilerOptions` --> `types`.

Comment: Is this preferred over `import path from "path"`?

Comment: For those who want to dig a bit deeper, the following link can be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697628/es6-import-as-alias-vs-import-alias

Answer (score 30):

If not using typescript

```
import * as path from 'path'
```

is the only thing that works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but look at Michael P. Bazos answer, he did mention that part aswell

Comment: Thanks Dharman, I thought it was appropriate to indicate this works with javascript, as Michael answer is specifically referring to Typescript.

Answer (score 16):

```
import path from 'path';
```

As of now, this is the code that's working for me in typescript.

Comment: Need to add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`. Also add `"esModuleInterop": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132668/69746

Comment: I keep coming back here several times a year!

Answer (score 15):

You can either do

`import module from 'path'`

or if you just need to import `path` just do

`import 'path'`

Comment: Somehow `import 'path'` with node 8.5 on Windows doesn't work anymore. I had to switch back to `const path = require('path')`

Comment: Also `import * as path from 'path';` is working with node 8.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

If the version of nodejs you're using supports the ES 6 features, then yes. Otherwise not.  Most of the older versions (pre 6.x if memory serves but you should check for your version) required the --harmony flag in order to do this, the latest releases include it natively.

For this reason, and because it works in all versions, most online resources still use the require syntax.