# ES6: "import * as alias" vs "import alias"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is there any difference between:

`import utils from 'utils'`

and

`import * as utils from 'utils'`?

**In case A:**

```
//utils.js
export function doSomething()
{
//...
}
```

**In case B:**

```
//utils.js
export function doSomething()
{
//...
}
export default function doSomethingDefault()
{
//...
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I was mislead by intellisense feature of vscode, but as recommended a small test on node+babel showed the difference:

```
//index.js
import utilsCaseA from './utils1'
import * as utilsCaseAWildcard from './utils1'
var utilsCaseARequire = require('./utils1')

import utilsCaseB from './utils2'
import * as utilsCaseBWildcard from './utils2'
var utilsCaseBRequire = require('./utils2')

var compareObjects = 
{
    utilsCaseA, utilsCaseAWildcard, utilsCaseARequire,utilsCaseB,utilsCaseBWildcard,utilsCaseBRequire
};
console.log(compareObjects);
```

[image]

Comment: Yes of course. Just try `console.log(utils)` to see the difference.

Comment: I just adjusted my question, please take a look. I don't see any difference for "Case A". Am I missing something?

Comment: Still, just look at what `utils` looks like. Yes, there is a difference!

Comment: You are right, default import for Case A is undefined. I was mislead by intellisense of vscode. Thanks!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From your example:

Case A:

```
//utils.js
export function doSomething()
{
//...
}
```

Case B:

```
//utils.js
export function doSomething()
{
//...
}
export default function doSomethingDefault()
{
//...
}
```

Result:

```
import utils from 'utils'
utils() // (Case A: undefined, Case B: doSomethingDefault)

import * as utils from 'utils'
utils // (Case A: utils = { doSomething: function }, Case B: utils = { doSomething: function, default: function })

import { doSomething } from 'utils'
doSomething() // (both Case A and Case B: doSomething = doSomething)
```

The difference between Case A and Case B is that, in Case A `import utils from 'utils'`, `utils` will be `undefined` because there is no default export. In case B, `utils` will refer  to `doSomethingDefault`.

With `import * as utils from 'utils'`, in Case A `utils` will have one method (`doSomething`), while in Case B `utils` will have two methods (`doSomething` and `default`).

Comment: Should we use export default as it can replace our default modules when creating library

Answer (score 19):

`import utils from 'utils'` imports default from 'utils' package. `undefined` in the case provided.

`import * as utils from 'utils'` imports entire module `exports` object with all available named exports including default.

Comment: I just adjusted my question, please take a look. I don't see any difference for "Case A". Am I missing something?

Comment: @PhilippMunin If you log `utils` in both cases you'll see the difference.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind I'll mark as an answer the inostia's response - few more scores will be encouraging for him

Comment: @PhilippMunin Sure. His answer is more relevant after the edit.

Comment: @PhilippMunin: I find this answer more succinct and clearer.