# TypeError: Loki is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, hapi, lokijs

I don't seem to be able to figure out why this is not working

My Hapi.js index.ts looks like this:

```
import { Server, Request, ResponseToolkit } from '@hapi/hapi';
import * as Loki from 'lokijs';
```

...

```
const db = new Loki(`${UPLOAD_PATH}/${DB_NAME}`, { persistenceMethod: 'fs' });
```

which is pretty straight forward, and is taken from a well known [example](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/handling-file-uploads-with-hapi-js)

The scripts in my package.json look like this:

```
"scripts": {
"prestart": "tsc",
"start": "node dist/index.js",
...
```

which compile into dist/index.js
When I run start, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Loki is not a constructor
```

I have tried all sort of things, but I guess I am missing the point, I'd be grateful if someone could please help me.
Loki is not a constructor, I get that, but how can I instantiate a new Loki(), and how come the same exact thing works elsewhere?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think the aliasing is tripping you up there, in that now the constructor is Loki,loki but i might be wrong.

Comment: Hi Joe, it was indeed the aliasing, and I forgot to include "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true into my tsconfig.json... Zishone's answer below is the accepted one, thank you for your kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either of the following:

```js
import * as Loki from 'lokijs';
const db = new Loki.default(`${UPLOAD_PATH}/${DB_NAME}`, { persistenceMethod: 'fs' });
// For me, I don't like this way. It looks bad.
```

or

```js
import Loki from 'lokijs';
const db = new Loki(`${UPLOAD_PATH}/${DB_NAME}`, { persistenceMethod: 'fs' });
```

Looking inside lokijs, the class seems to be exported as `module.exports = factory()`, equivalent to `export default factory()`, so the class is exported as `default`. Here is a helpful question to undestand what I mean: [ES6: "import * as alias" vs "import alias"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45697628/es6-import-as-alias-vs-import-alias)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @zishone, the second snippet did the trick, with one minor amendment: make sure that your tsconfig.json includes "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true. (my bad...) Have a great weekend my friend