# Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js

Using es2015 presets but still import doesn' work

```
import corsPrefetch from 'cors-prefetch-middleware';  
import imagesUpload from 'images-upload-middleware';
```

ERROR

```
import corsPrefetch from 'cors-prefetch-middleware';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: which version of node are you using?

Comment: node version - 6.9.4

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39436580/3621001)

Comment: I m already compiling using babel @SyedAliTaqi

Comment: Does it work using Babel? can we see your `.babelrc` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js doesn't support es6 module syntax yet. You have to use:

```
var corsPrefetch = require('cors-prefetch-middleware');
```

or use babel with the es2015 preset to transpile your es6 code back to es5:

```
"build": "babel --out-dir dist --presets=es2015
```