# why import in es6 not working here?

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is my code

```
// var htmlplugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); // works!

import htmlplugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'; //not working
```

when I npm run dev shows erros like:

```
import htmlplugin from 'html-webpack-plugin'
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` is not yet supported in Node.js. Node.js uses Google's V8 for its JavaScript engine. The version of V8 currently shipping with Node.js does not support `import`. (I don't think even the most recent V8 supports it without a command line flag.)

Once `import` *is* supported, it still might not support CommonJS modules like those typically installed by `npm` (although perhaps it will because there is some ambitious work on interoperability--time will tell).

Comment: Thank you very much