# Javascript ECMAscript 6 Cant run script with import classes

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Im learn Selenium Webdriver. I cant run script with import classes, but i can run it without classes, just with import function. Im run it with babel-cli like this `node ./babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js --presets node6 ./test.js`

```
//test.js
import homePage from "./home_page"

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

home_page = new homePage(driver);
home_page.go_home_page();

//home_page.js
export default class homePage{
    constructor(driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }
     go_home_page = function(){
        this.driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

error is :`home_page.js: Unexpected token (5:15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node was originally [built with CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_modules), and the transition to ES2015 modules [will not be easy](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c).

Your example is using both: `import` is ES2015, and `require` is CommonJS. If you change your `import` to `require` it should work.

The CommonJS equivalent for that `import` should look like:

```
var homePage = require('./home_page');
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules

Comment: Since you're using babel, it _should_ be possible to use `import` but I'm not familiar enough to tell you what needs to be done. I do know that the target ES version and module system needs to be configured specifically, although the preset should do a lot of that work for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how import my class with require? Please.

Answer (score -1):

es6 need to use babel to transpile. you need to include babel in your package json file.

Comment: im run it with `node ./babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js --presets node6 ./test.js`