# Why transpile node.js backend code?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, transpiler

I am new to es6 and have two questions

1. Is transpiling really required for backend code (node.js) written in es6 ?
2. If transpiling is not necessary - is there a disadvantage running plain es6 on server side - can it affect debugging  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules)

Answer (score 1):

Answer can be debatable. I strongly feel there is no need of transpiling your backend code (NodeJS). Transpiling converts your import/export statements to require, module.exports. Which you can directly use in NodeJs.

Also, on client side, it makes sense to have transpilation for different `browser support` and also it reduces the `bundle size`. But for NodeJS side, there is also a disadvantage for debugging.

Comment: what is the disadvantage in debugging ?