# Why require.requireActual/getMockFromModule default property must be access to get exported module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Based on https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/manual-mocks/models/user.js examples I created my own manual mock:

```
const RandomNumber = require.requireActual('../RandomNumber');
RandomNumber.prototype.generate = function() {
  return this.min;
};
export default RandomNumber;
```

For this module:

```
export default class {
  constructor(min, max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  generate() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.max - this.min + 1) + this.min);
  }
}
```

However I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'generate' of undefined

I turned out that I need to add `.default` on object that is returned from `requireActual`. And the same applies to code that uses `getMockFromModule`:

```
const RandomNumberMock = jest.genMockFromModule('../RandomNumber').default;
RandomNumberMock.prototype.generate.mockReturnValue(10);
export default RandomNumberMock;
```

I didn't see any mention about this in Jest docs, nor their examples use `.default` property.

Any idea why in my basic setup this is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Because this is how `require` (CommonJS) works, other than using `ES6 Modules` that already do import default.

Tl;DR;
ES6's `export default someClass` is similar to CommonJS's `module.export = { default: someClass }`

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677972/4708072) out.