# React-native creating switch navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a beginner in react-native. I am trying to create a navigator sidebar and i have an error regarding creating the switch navigator. I have followed tutorials but i came up with an error

Require cycle: modules\Dashboard.js -> modules\Navigator.js -> modules\Dashboard.js

I have this in my Navigator.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

//navigators
import Dashboard from '../modules/Dashboard.js'

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH*0.83,
}

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        dashboard: {
            screen: Dashboard
        },
    },
    DrawerConfig
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

class Navigator extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContainer />
          );
    }
}
```

and Here is my fullcode from Dashboard.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

import MenuButton from '../modules/MenuButton.js'
import Navigator from '../modules/Navigator.js'


class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <Navigator />
            <MenuButton navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                <Text style={styles.smallBlue}>Dashboard</Text>
            </View>
          );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

//Views
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

//Text
  smallBlue: {
          marginTop: 30,
          color: 'powderblue',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          fontSize: 30,
  }
});

export default Dashboard
```

Is this because i imported already dashboard from my navigator and my dashboard imported my navigator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is import issue as described in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664673/require-cycles-are-allowed-but-can-result-in-uninitialized-values-consider-ref)

You should not use **Navigator** in your dashboard screen. it should be in your app register component

**index.js**

```
import Navigator from "./Navigator";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Navigator);
```

**Navigator.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

//navigators
import Dashboard from '../modules/Dashboard.js'

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH*0.83,
}

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        dashboard: {
            screen: Dashboard
        },
    },
    DrawerConfig
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

export default class Navigator extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContainer />
          );
    }
}
```

Update For Expo

Update App.js file and add Navigator.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

//navigators
import Dashboard from '../modules/Dashboard.js'

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
    drawerWidth: WIDTH*0.83,
}

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        dashboard: {
            screen: Dashboard
        },
    },
    DrawerConfig
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

export default class Navigator extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContainer />
          );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, do i need to make register component file ?

Comment: do you mean i need to make index.js as register component and import it in my dashboard?

Comment: no when you create a new project you have index.js file just change this line AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Navigator); in your index.js file to make  Navigator as your app registry component

Comment: hello sir, may i know where is index.js located in expo ?

Comment: if you are using expo change here node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js  registerRootComponent(App); see this [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/)