# How to fix Require cycle warning In React Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting this error.[ErrorImg][1]
This is Require cycles error but I can't find what is the reason.
I want to use ListItem component to View.js through component.js and I already use that like this **import {ListItem } from '../components/';**.
The result is good but there is this warning and I want to fix. Please help me.

Require cycle: Components.js->

````
import Button from './Button';
import Select from './Select';
import Icon from './Icon';
import Tabs from './Tabs';
import Product from './Product';
import Drawer from './Drawer';
import Header from './Header';
import Switch from './Switch';
import ListItem from './ListItem';
import HorizontalListItem from './HorizontalListItem';
export {
    Button,
    Select,
    Icon,
    Tabs,
    Product,
    Drawer,
    Header,
    Switch,
    ListItem,
    HorizontalListItem,
};```

View.js->

```const renderPatientsList = () => {
      return(
        <Block style={{ paddingHorizontal: theme.SIZES.BASE }}>
            <ScrollView vertical={true} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={{marginBottom: theme.SIZES.BASE * 3}}>
                <ListItem product={products[0]} horizontal />
                <ListItem product={products[1]} horizontal />
                <ListItem product={products[2]} horizontal />
            </ScrollView>    
        </Block>
      )
  }```

ListItem.js -->

```import React from 'react';
import { withNavigation } from '@react-navigation/compat';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { Block, Text, theme } from 'galio-framework';
import { Icon } from '../components/';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');

const ListItem = props => {
  const { navigation, product, horizontal, full, style, priceColor, imageStyle, time, unReaden, weekday } = props;
  const imageStyles = [styles.image, full ? styles.fullImage : styles.horizontalImage, imageStyle];

  return (
        
      <Block row={horizontal} card flex style={[styles.product, styles.shadow, style]}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Product', { product: product })}>
            <Block style={[styles.imageContainer, styles.shadow]}>
              <Image source={{ uri: product.image }} style={imageStyles}/>
            </Block>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Product', { product: product })}>
            <Block flex={3}>
              <Text size={16} style={styles.userName}>{product.title}</Text>
              <Block flexDirection={'row'}>
                <Icon name="photo" family="font-awesome" color={theme.COLORS.MUTED} size={theme.SIZES.BASE} style={styles.icons}> </Icon>  
                <Icon name="check" family="font-awesome" color={theme.COLORS.MUTED} size={theme.SIZES.BASE} style={styles.icons}> </Icon>  
                <Text size={16} muted={!priceColor} color={priceColor}>${product.price}</Text>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Product', { product: product })}>
            <Block flex={1}>
              <>
                {(product.time) ? (
                  <Text size={12} style={styles.times} color={"#06D81E"}>{product.time}</Text>
                ) : (
                  <Text size={12} style={styles.times} color={"#000"}>{product.weekday}</Text>
                )}
              </>
              
              <Block style={{borderRadius: 100, backgroundColor: "#06D81E", width: theme.SIZES.BASE * 1.2, height: theme.SIZES.BASE * 1.2, position: "absolute", right: theme.SIZES.BASE, bottom: theme.SIZES.BASE}}>
                <Text size={12} center style={{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} color={"#FFF"} fontWeight={"semiBold"}>{product.unReaden}</Text>
              </Block>
            </Block>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </Block>
  );
}```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDB6i.png
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are getting require cycle warning because you end up creating a loop ( require from `Component.js` in `ListItem.js` and require from `ListItem.js` in `Component.js`)

In `ListItem.js`,

```
import {Icon} from Icon.js
```

The general idea is to write the module in another file and import that module from there.

see this for a detailed explanation:
[Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55664673/require-cycles-are-allowed-but-can-result-in-uninitialized-values-consider-ref)