# Cannot find module '../models/user' Node.js on Server

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules, ts-node

i can start my node app fine on my local machine but if i then pull the project from github on my server and start it with `npm start` i get this error:

> Cannot find module '../models/user'.
>
> > import User = require('../models/user');

**registrationController.ts** is trying to access the **models/user**.

This is how i import in that file:

```
import User = require('../models/user');
```

This is my folder structure. I get the error in the highlighted file:

[image]

This is my `npm start` script:

```js
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon --watch '*.ts' --exec 'ts-node' app.ts"
}
```

Comment: What file is trying to access `models/user`? Could you show us the code for that and where it is in the directory?

Comment: registrationController.ts is trying to access it. I updated the question

Comment: did you mark this as 'release' by any chance, on github or elsewhere?

Comment: I think it should be `import User from '../models/user';` or `const User = require('../models/user');`. Assuming `user.ts` has a default export

Comment: doesn't fix the issue @kaleidawave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the correct syntax to use your user model into the controllers, you should assign the required model directly to a variable (either a const or var) as follow:

```
const User = require('../models/user');
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x) has great details regarding the two ways (import and require).

Comment: doesn't fix the issue unfortunately

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS Hope that you exported the module from the user model.

Comment: My filename was User.ts on bitbucket instead of user.ts

I pushed it to bitbucket before with user.ts but the filename hasn't changed there!!! So i had to remove the whole project from bitbucket

Comment: Ok, but according to your question, I think my answer is correct :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like mixing the es6 syntax with older syntax

use this way if you are exporting that module as a default export

```
import User from '../models/user';
```

otherwise use

```
const User = require('../models/user')
```

make sure you are exporting the module like this

```
module.exports = <Your Module>
```

Answer (score 0):

My filename was User.ts on bitbucket instead of user.ts

I pushed it to bitbucket before with user.ts but the filename hasn't changed there!!! So i had to remove the whole project from bitbucket