# How to use the import statement properly?

Tags: typescript, npm, import

I want to try the following **npm** package, [camera-capture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camera-capture),  to capture videos from my webcam.
I am very new to both **npm** and **typescript**, so I'm not sure how to test it properly. 
What I did so far is the following:

1. Copied [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camera-capture#managed-frame-read), then saved it in an `index.js` file
2. Tried executing it from the terminal using `node index.js`

I received the following error:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I know that what I'm doing might be so wrong, however, as a beginner, the explanation on the package's homepage is not enough for me, I need to know about further steps to make it work properly.

My question is: How to set the proper environment to run a test for this library?

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved the `import` problem specifically by the following:

1. Copied this example, then saved it in an `index.ts` file
2. Compiled it using `tsc index.ts`,
3. Executed the resulting `js` file from the terminal using `node index.js`

This resolved the `import` problem. However, other problems were thrown (not related to this question, as I think),

Answer (score -1):

You could try

> const VideoCapture=require('camera-capture')

instead of

> import {VideoCapture} from 'camera-capture'

Comment: that makes it "somehow" work, but that's not a complete answer. I have been searching around and I found this question that explains the difference between `import` and `require` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x