# Using Jest to test code that contains undefined functions

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to write unit tests for some JavaScript code I have. The problem is that the code file contains functions that aren't defined or imported, so when I try to import the file to test, Jest throws an error about the undefined functions. Is there a way I can get around this? Only import the functions I want to test, for example?

Here's a snippet of the file with the code that I'm trying to test:

```js
// run any data migrations
on("sheet:opened", () => {
    sheetMigration();

    getAttrs(["btatow_sheet_version"], ({
        btatow_sheet_version
    }) => {
        if (btatow_sheet_version >= 3) {
            recalculateSkills();
        }
    });
});

...

// calculate stat values when XP amount changes
on("change:strength_xp change:body_xp change:reflex_xp change:dexterity_xp change:intelligence_xp change:will_xp change:charisma_xp change:edge_xp", calculateAbilityScore)

const calculateLinkedAttributeValue = attribute => {
    if (attribute > 10) {
        return Math.floor(attribute / 3);
    } else {
        if (attribute < 1)
            return -4;
        else if (attribute < 2)
            return -2;
        else if (attribute < 4)
            return -1;
        else if (attribute < 7)
            return 0;
        else if (attribute < 10)
            return 1;
        else
            return 2;
    }
}

...

// exports for testing
module.exports = calculateLinkedAttributeValue
```

Here's the code in the test file:

```js
const calculateLinkedAttributeValue = require('./sheet-worker')

test('should calculate linked attribute value for attribute value of 0', () => {
    expect(calculateLinkedAttributeValue(0)).toBe(-4)
})
```

I have a `package.json` file set up, and have brought in Jest as a dependency, like so:

```
{
  "name": "battletech-a-time-of-war",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Character sheet for Roll20 for the A Time of War TTRPG system.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.0.1"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Attempting to run the tests via the command line produces the following output:

```sh
C:\Stuff\Development\roll20-character-sheets\BattleTech-A-Time-of-War\development>npm run test

> battletech-a-time-of-war@1.0.0 test C:\Stuff\Development\roll20-character-sheets\BattleTech-A-Time-of-War
> jest

 FAIL  development/sheet-worker.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: on is not defined

      1 | // run any data migrations
    > 2 | on("sheet:opened", () => {
        | ^
      3 |     sheetMigration();
      4 |
      5 |     getAttrs(["btatow_sheet_version"], ({

      at Object.<anonymous> (development/sheet-worker.js:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (development/sheet-worker.test.js:1:39)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.226 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! battletech-a-time-of-war@1.0.0 test: `jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the battletech-a-time-of-war@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-01T09_59_15_484Z-debug.log
```

EDIT: Add examples and remove link to GitHub source code.

Comment: Define all of them as globals and clean them up after a test. Please, update the question with the code, it should be understandable without navigating to external resource which can become unavailable. It's not unnecessary to paste a thousand of lines, just https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The question needs more focus. You have too much code

Comment: What should I remove from the question? I've tried to include the minimal information; the code that I'm trying to test, along with the code that's causing the problem, the test code, and the error output. I included the `package.json` as I thought that may be relevant to the question, in case I have Jest set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around for a while on the internet and trying different things, I was able to determine the cause of the problem. It's actually nothing to do with Jest, it's the Node `require()` function. I found out from [this StackOverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x#comment110019241_46677972) that the Node `require()` function basically runs all the code in the file you're importing. Hence it tries to run the undefined functions, and errors.