# Import a class without using require

Tags: typescript

I would like to know the difference between creating a class and exporting it later and creating a class with the keyword export at the beginning

First use case:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
  }
  // ...
}
export = Foo;
```

Second use case:

```
export class Foo {
  constructor() {
  }
  // ...
}
```

The reason I am asking is that when I use the first approach, I always have to import the class in another module like this:

```
import Foo = require("./Foo");
```

and when I use the second approach, I can import it like this:

```
import {Foo} from "./Foo";
```

I have two questions: Whats the difference between these two approaches? and is there a way to export the class to import a class without using `require` while keeping the first approach ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between "require(x)" and "import x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x)

Comment: The real difference is between `export = Foo` and `export Foo`. Try getting rid of the `=`…

Answer (score 1):

Require Is a method Introduced By NodeJs, While Import is a EcmaScript/TypeScript method,

You can use both in nodejs because nodejs supports EcmaScript too, but you cannot use require in other programs