# Conditional Import of Library in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, importerror

I am trying to do this:

```js
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  import Keyboard from "react-simple-keyboard"
  import "react-simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css"
}
```

But I get

`'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (12:2)`

Anything I can do about this? I need to load my keyboard only if we're in the browser. Not during build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`React.lazy`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) for the component, and `require()`.

> The `React.lazy` function lets you render a dynamic import as a regular component.

```
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  import Keyboard from "react-simple-keyboard"
  import "react-simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css"
}

// Becomes
if (typeof window !== `undefined`) {
  // Component
  const Keyboard = React.lazy(() => import('react-simple-keyboard'));

  // Resolve
  require('react-simple-keyboard/build/css/index.css');
}
```

- See [import vs require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x/46677972#:%7E:text=The%20major%20difference%20between%20require,act%20the%20same%20as%20require%20.)
- Moreover, you should check for [`import()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does let me build it. But I get an `illegal constructor` error when I run it any idea why this might be? would I do this type of import where I do the other imports (that's where I put it so far)?

Comment: I don't know and its not related to your question, you should ask a new question with your current problem.

Comment: It is related. I am asking you where in my code I need to put the code that you suggested. Next to the other imports? In a function? Right now it's crashing, unfortunately.

Comment: You put it instead of your current your code, that's how you make dynamic imports. I can't tell your exactly in which file, I can't know your project structure.

Comment: That's fine. I don't need to know which file. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the dynamic import syntax

const Keyboard = import('react-simple-keyboard')

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby supports dynamic imports out of the box.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function dynamicImportModule() {
    const dynamicModule = (await import('some-module'))
    // perform remaining tasks with dynamicModule
  }

  dynamicImportModule()
}, [someDependency])
```

Comment: I always end up with a "MyComponent is not defined" when in the useEffect