# NodeJS - using require works import does not work

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm trying to understand why `require` works while `import` does not for an npm package. The package is `r7insight_node` and allows us to send our logs to their product, Rapid7. When we use `require` as [per their instructions](https://github.com/rapid7/r7insight_node#using-as-a-winston-transport) things work fine, but don't when I use `import`.

Their library has an `src/index.js` file that looks like:

```
//  Use codependency for dynamically loading winston
const requirePeer = codependency.register(module);

//  Import winston
const winston = requirePeer('winston', {optional: true});
const Transport = requirePeer('winston-transport', {optional: true});

//  If we have successfully loaded winston (user has it)
//  we initialize our InsightTransport
if (winston) {
  provisionWinston(winston, Transport);
}

//  Logger is default export
module.exports = Logger;
//  Export as `bunyanStream` to not break existing integration
module.exports.bunyanStream = buildBunyanStream;
module.exports.provisionWinston = provisionWinston;
```

My understanding is that `require` is synchronous and is "computed" whereas `import` is asynchronous and is NOT "computed" as [written here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677972/260574). Is this the reason for why `require` works while `import` does not?

Does "computed" mean in that the `index.js` file is executed and hence the `if (winston)` block is checked and executed in a `require` but not in an `import`? Is there a way to achieve the same using `import` statements?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a module to work with `import`, it has to be designed to be compatible with `import`  and the caller has to import it the right way.  Modules designed for `require()` are NOT automatically compatible with `import`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the package to work with the ES6 import way, it has to be written to it, it has to be exported as eg:`export default Logger` and not `module.exports = Logger`, hope my answer helped you