# What is meaning of this command? import DataTypes = require('./lib/data-types');

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import DataTypes = require('./lib/data-types')
```

Please someone explain to me. Why can use import and require together. This is in a module of NodeJS. Sequelize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between "require(x)" and "import x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x)

Comment: Also [RTM](https://sequelize.org/master/variable/index.html#static-variable-DataTypes)

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is specific to TypeScript. See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.
> When exporting a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import module = require("module") must be used to import the module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Typescript syntax.

Try using

```
import * as x from 'x'
```

Or

```
const … = require(…)
```