# TypeScript: import = require vs import from

Tags: typescript

When should you use this syntax:

```
import SomeName = require(“something”)
```

Instead of:

```
import SomeName from “something”
```

Or:

```
const SomeName = require(“something”]
```

EDIT: excuse the lack of detail and context, I was too quick in posting this. I am very aware of CommonJS and ESM and was specifically looking for why one would use the `import SomeName = require(“something”)` form. I come across it occasionally but never use it myself. For some reason, it was hard to google this, but I’ve now found the answer in the TypeScript docs.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x

Comment: I don't think the first one is valid at all, you'd only see equals and import together with [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export)

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is in fact valid syntax. First time I saw it I thought wtf is this

Comment: @Nishant @ kaya3 thanks but those pages don’t explain the particular import form I was looking to understand: import x = require(“x”)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

> Both CommonJS and AMD generally have the concept of an exports object which contains all exports from a module.
>
> They also support replacing the exports object with a custom single object. Default exports are meant to act as a replacement for this behavior; however, the two are incompatible. TypeScript supports export = to model the traditional CommonJS and AMD workflow.
>
> The export = syntax specifies a single object that is exported from the module. This can be a class, interface, namespace, function, or enum.
>
> When exporting a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import module = require("module") must be used to import the module.