# How can I import a JS file with special characters in it's name in React and JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-syntax-highlighter

How can I import a  JS file with special characters in it's name in React and JSX?

I can

`import { tomorrow} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';`

(the folder contains tomorrow.js and tomrorrow-night.js)

but I can't:

`import { tomorrow-night} from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';`

I don't think destructuring works here because it's an import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try as

```
import * as Highlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';

const TomorrowNight = Highlighter[`tomorrow-night`];
```

Comment: thanks for answer but one thing I found out is after importing the name now is in Snake format instead of kabab format ,I mean `const tmrw_night=Highlighter['tomorrowNight']`
any idea why?

Comment: file name would be in kabab case so while requiring you import from file in kabab. while function would be exported in snake case. not sure until we see script in details. check this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `import * as blah` import? That gives you an object that you can then lookup any string in.

```js
import * as tmrw from from 'react-syntax-highlighter/dist/esm/styles/hljs';
const tmrw_night = tmrw['tomorrow-height']
```

Comment: thanks for answer but one thing I found out is after importing the name now is in Snake format instead of kabab format ,I mean `const tmrw_night=tmrw['tomorrowNight']`
dont know why