# wildcard import in javascript... does it work using `with` under the hood?

Tags: javascript, wildcard, require, javascript-import

So I know imports can be replaced with `require`.

`import {x} from 'x'` is equivalent to `const {x} = require('x')`.

But what about `import * from 'x'` ? the only thing that I can imagine it being translated to is `with(require('x')){... }`.

Yet `with` statements are frown upon, aren't they? (because you don't know in compile time how a reference will be resolved)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import * from "x";
```

is not valid JS.

```js
import * as x from "x";
```

is.

How is that different from

```js
import x from "x";
```

?

Well, the latter requires you to have a default export, while the former takes all the exports and groups them into one object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the syntax confused. This:

```
import * from 'x'
```

is not valid. What you *can* do is:

```
import * as x from 'x';
```

This puts all the exports from the `x` file into the *namespace* (which is, for the most part, just a JavaScript object whose properties and `default` correspond to the names of the exports). The `x` identifier that gets imported refers to this namespace.

Also

> `import {x} from 'x'` is equivalent to `const {x} = require('x').`

is not correct - `require` is CommonJS syntax, and `import`/`export` is ES6 module syntax. They're [not interchangeable *by default*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x), though they do very similar things.