# Why my code work with require but don't work with import Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, export

I am beginner in Node JS.I have questions...
I want to export multiple modules is node with module.exports when i use requre my code work but don't work with import {} from.I know Node js doesen't provide ES6.But if i change my package.json
and write type:module it can work.With export default my app work with import but with module.exports it can't work.
I asked because in my last interview i got this question.And in my fitback there was this:Exporting multiple entities
with
<exports.[name-of-entity]>

Please help rosolve it))

```
import lib from "./index2.js"

lib.double()
```

```
function double(){
    return console.log('Hello double')
}

function trouble(){
    return console.log('Hello trouble!')
}

module.exports = {
    double,
    trouble
}
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import` and `require` are not the same.

This link is informative

[The difference between "require(x)" and "import x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x)

Comment: Thank u soo much!