# What is the problem of mixing require and import in the same typescript file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a nodejs project writing in typescript. In some ts file I use `require` and `import` together, e.g. when using [debugjs](https://github.com/debug-js/debug) because it has cjs module only. I know there is [@types/debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/debug) but since debugjs usage is rather straightforward I don't bother to use it. But [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) is another story because I feel [@types/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express) can help me better use express.

I know the difference between cjs and ej module, e.g. as [Using Node.js require vs. ES6 import/export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354559/using-node-js-require-vs-es6-import-export) discussed, but since my ts files will be transpiled into cjs running inside nodejs (I don't use `mjs` or set `"type": "module"` in package.json), what is the problem is mixing `require` and `import` in the same typescript file?

So far I have not noticed any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Cases where it is necessary to use both`require` and `import` in a single file, are quite rare and it is generally not recommended and considered not a good practice. However, sometimes it is the easiest way for us to solve a problem. There are always trade-offs and the decision is up to you. But, If you use ES6 module, recommended using `import`.

Additionally, the difference between commonJS `require` and ES6 `import` is

- With `require`, cannot load pieces you need to load, but with `import`, you can selectively load only the pieces you need, which can save memory.
- Regarding performance, `import` is a little faster/better than `require` since it is `asynchronous`, but `require` is `synchronous`.

Comment: But in the end all ts files will be transpiled into cjs js files run in nodejs, so I really doubt these points are valid.

Comment: "import is a little faster/better than require since it is asynchronous" --- what this statement is based on? asynchronisity does not make anything quicker (it's actually the opposite).

Comment: Loading is synchronous(step by step) for `require` on the other hand `import` can be asynchronous(without waiting for previous import) so it can perform a little better than `require`.

Comment: Even this is the case for a server side app, it really doesn't matter