# How to convert require( "./handlers/event.js")(client) in es6?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to convert `require( "./handlers/event.js")(client)` to es6 but can't find how to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between "require(x)" and "import x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line is importing from a module that looks like this

```
module.exports = function(client) {
  this.newClient = function() {
    var x = client()
    // ...
  }
}
```

Which in ES6 would look like this

```
export default function(client) {
  this.newClient = function() {
    var x = client()
    // ...
  }
  return this
}
```

For importing that in an ES6 way, should be something like

```
import FOO from "./handlers/event"
```

And then you can do something like

```
const { newClient } = FOO(new Client())
const p = newClient() // or anything you want to do with it
```