# I want to import all command files from a folder and execute them in ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, discord.js

In my guild command file I have to require all files of the commands folder and save them as a variable in a FOR-Loop.

In ES5 it would look like that:

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
   const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
   commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

But I want to import everything with ES6 and the import statement.
Is there a way to convert the code above to ES6-compatible code?

Comment: Please add an example of the code in these "command files". Is it ES6-ready as well?

Comment: What makes you think the above code is not "ES6-compatible"? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[require(x) vs import x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677972)

Dynamic `import()` returns a promise, that's why you have to use `await` before it.

If the module exported as `default`, you should use `const { default: command } = await import(x)`, if you want to use `const command`, use `command.default` instead of `command` later in the code.

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = await import(`../commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Try using *`FS`* || *`FileSystem`*:**

```js
const fs = require("fs"); // Import the FileSystem

fs.readdirSync(`../commands`).forEach(file => {
  const command = require(`../commands/${file}`); // Saving the imported file as a constant
  // Do something with the "command" constant
});
```

### Explaination:

- First we import *`FileSystem`* || *`FS`*.
- Then we use *`FS`*'s "`readdirSync()`" function to get all the files from the "`commands`" directory.
- As we get all the file names from the "`commands`" folder, we import each of them as "`command`" constant.
- Now all the content of "`file`" is stored in the "`command`" constant.
- Now everything is done and you can write your code.

*If you have any other questions, related to this code, please feel free to ask me them in the comments.*