# How to properly send a message from firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Im trying to learn how to read the official firebase docs. but I cant seem to get it right

I want to send notifications from a cloud function to a phone, but I was only able to do it using some functions not found on the docs ( see code below )

I know the docs  say to use getMessaging().send(message), but I cant get it to work {see image attached}

[image: cloud function]

code where I am able to send notification

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
const tokens = ["REDACTED_TOKEN"];

admin.initializeApp();

exports.onCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat/{docId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      console.log("fake data");
    });

exports.onUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat messages/{docId}")
    .onCreate( (snapshot, context) => {
      const payload = {
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        notification: {title: "Push Title", body: "Push Body", sound: "default"},
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        data: {click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", message: "Sample Push Message"},
      };

      try {
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION SEND SUCCESFULLY");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR SENDING NOTIFICATION");
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message

Comment: You may want to edit your screenshot and code snippet to redact your tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably interested in something like this:

```
const messaging = require("firebase-admin/messaging");

messaging.getMessaging() //continued with what you want to accomplish.
```

The firebase-admin node package has a sub packaging for messaging where `getMessaging()` lives, but [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.messaging) also seems to note that `getMessaging()` is the equivalent of `admin.messaging()` so using getMessaging() would make your functions closer in line with the documentation. If you wanted to be even more similar to the documentation, you may want to [switch from require to import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46677972/3946096) to selectively load only the parts of the package you need. An example of using import instead of require may look like this:

```
import {getMessaging} from 'firebase-admin/messaging';
getMessaging().send(message);
```