load data dependent on language – can’t get dynamic javascript import to work (vanilla JS)
I want to load some javascript data dependent on the user’s language (not translation files). In PHP I would just go if ($lang == 'de') { include 'data-de.php'; } else { include 'data-en.php'; }, or something to that effect.
I understand it doesn’t work like that in JS, and I’ve looked into dynamic imports. This is what I have after determining the language to use (the value of lang):
// in data-{lang}.js
export const points = [{"id":"Q230416", …}, {…}, …];

// in map.js
import('./data-'+lang+'.js')
  .then((data) => {
    const points = data.points;
    console.log(data.points);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

This gives me all my points in the log alright. However, how can I use them elsewhere? (The way I went about this is I wrote all the functionality with a fixed data set, and now I am retrofitting different data sets dependent on language – maybe that is not the best way to do it.)
I am pretty sure I’m missing something very basic here, like I haven’t understood all the relevant concepts yet – but I just can’t figure out what exactly I need to dive deeper into. Any pointers are much appreciated!

"…how can I use them elsewhere?": Using JavaScript modules, you can export the awaited result of a dynamic import() statement (e.g. export const { points } = await import(`./data-${lang}.js`);). If that answers your question, I can write it as one (or find a duplicate target question) — if not, what did I miss?

Where you write console.log(data.points); you can also write myfavouriteglobalvariable=data.points;.

If your code runs on Node.js, require() may help too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x
