# Node.js giving SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

I am following the code from [here](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/fit-curve.html) which doesn't mention any special requirements apart from Node.js being version 8.9 or higher. I am new to javascript and I am unsure as to why the import function does not work unless there are additional requirements not specified in the link.

I am getting a syntax error when I try to use 'import' in javascript:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'
import {generateData} from './data';
```

which returns the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I know that in older versions there used to be problems with the import but I am using the up to date versions for node, npm, and yarn so I am not sure why I am getting this error. The snippet of code that I am running on says that it requires node.js of version 8.9 or higher (which is satisfied) as well as either npm or yarn.

```
node -v
v8.10.0

npm -v
6.1.0

yarn -v
1.7.0
```

[Also as of 2017, the import function should work in ES6 with node.js.](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c)

Comment: @Hector I am quite new to javascript but the link that I was following https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/fit-curve.html, didn't mention need for an experimental-modules flag

Comment: It can be a bit difficult to find information on it, but take a look at the following as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules

...it appears it may be a bit of a wait?

Comment: @AndyGaskell it is actually in the $ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-examples repository. There is actually a line before it `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'` that also doesn't work. for the same reason The json file is called index.js and is found within the  the polynomial-regression-core folder in the github directory

Comment: @Hector According to this https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/an-update-on-es6-modules-in-node-js-42c958b890c , the import function should work now

Comment: @ImranRashid Read this: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-es6-babel-nodejs-harshal-yeole/

Comment: Thanks @Jack that was useful.