# How can I make ES6 imports work in node 12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

> **Edit**: This is not a duplicate of [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules). That question is asking about node's plans. **This is a specific technical error now those plans have been implemented. Please read questions before you mark them as duplicate.**

[Node 12 supports ES modules using the `--experimental-modules` flag](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules). However when I try to use the [`import *` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) it fails:

```
> import * as record from 'src/frontend/rrweb.js'                                                               Thrown:
import * as record from 'src/frontend/rrweb.js'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Likewise:

```
import {record} from 'src/frontend/rrweb.js'
```

Fails with the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? How can I import an ES6 module?

**Updates**

Loading an `.mjs` does not work:

```
$ node --experimental-modules .\deleteme.js                                                  (node:18292) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.                                    C:\Users\mikem\Code\appless\deleteme.js:1
import {record} from 'src/frontend/rrweb.mjs'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

Comment: did you try putting it in a file and running `node ./yourFile.js`?

Comment: @silicakes I did that - it executes fine without errors. I;m not sure whether node would use the ES6 syntax to run the module in that case though.

Comment: Did you add the `type` field to package.json, or use the `--input-type` cmd flag?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree it is duplicate, because the answer is (likely) the accepted answer in the linked post:  you need to set `type: "module"` in the `package.json`. Perhaps its vague though - if that does solve your question maybe its worth making this Q&A specifically making this point.

Comment: Here's a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node apparently you'll need to save your files as `.mjs`

Comment: @MeirionHughes Yes, there is a `package.json` with `"type": "module"` in the same dir as `rrweb.js`

Comment: Alas @silicakes `.mjs` doesn't work either. See output above.

Comment: works for me™ with `"type": "module"` and `node -v : 12.2.0` and `foo.js` `import {Bar} from './bar.js` and `node --experimental-modules foo.js`. the only caveat is that the import explicitly had to have the file extension; i.e. couldn't find `"./bar"`. I'd suggest sanity checking node version and the flag