# Serverless Deployment failing due to usage of require AND import

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I know it is a bad practice to use the `import` as well as `require` statements in the same file, but I heard it shouldn't cause any problems.
Why will my lambda fail then (when running `yarn run local`) and complain about an 'Unexpected Identifier' when encountering the `import` statement?
[Here's the current codebase](https://github.com/GitGangGuy/serverless-sapper-edge). The problem lies in the functions/edge.js file.

**EDIT:** I'm sorry I haven't clearly formulated my question. Replacing the import statement with the seemingly equivalent `const middleware = require('@sapper/server');` results in an error: It can't find the module - with import it works perfectly fine, even during production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because AWS Lambdas run on node, and the version of node AWS Lambda use don't support `import` keyword.

More info on [NodeJS plans to support import/export es6 (es2015) modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules)

EDIT: As [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1445636/michael) states in the comments, you need to install the proper packages. Either by using `npm` or looking where the package should be (I guess you should follow [sapper.svelte](https://sapper.svelte.dev/) instructions properly). `import` would fail the same way as `require` as the package don't exists. Is not an "import vs require" problem, but a non-existent package problem.

Comment: How can I do the same import I'm doing in `functions/edge.js` with require() instead?

Comment: The same way you do all the other imports in that file - use `const middleware = require("modulename")`

Comment: @SearchingSolutions as Michael says, `require('@sapper/server');` in this case. An import is nothing more than a fancy require.

Comment: @Michael That's the problem: While the import statement would work perfectly fine, `require ('@sapper/server')` instead of importing it throws an error - it somehow can't find the module. Are you sure that's how you import namespaces with require?

Comment: Positive - it looks like you're missing the `@sapper/server` from your package JSON dependencies section which will be causing it to not be found. `npm i --save @sapper/server`

Comment: @Michael I updated the import statement and changed it into an equivalent require statement. When running `yarn run local` (Serverless local invocation) it can't find the module. I can't require `sapper` directly. How can I import `@sapper/server` like with an import (see `src/server.js` for the original implementation)?

Comment: @SearchingSolutions I've edited my answer. `@sapper` seems part of `sveltle`. You must follow their indications so you can have `@sapper` installed.