# ES 2015 Import all using asterisk

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, casbin

I'm implementing [node-casbin](https://github.com/casbin/node-casbin) in my project. I tried importing everything into my project using the code below.

```
import * as casbin from 'casbin';
```

When I save my Node.js server crashes with the error below.

```
import * as casbin from 'casbin';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436322/node-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import/39436580

TL;DR your node version may not (fully) support `import`. Have you tried using `require`?

Comment: @Damon What version supports ES 2015? I'm using v10.16.0.

Comment: Even Node 12 still requires an opt in via the `--experimental-modules` flag. https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling

Your node version supports most ES features (see https://node.green/), just not ES modules unless you use the flag and follow the setup. This answer has a good summary of some of the gory details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules

Comment: Your best bet would be to do `const casbin = require('casbin')` unless you feel a strong existential need to use ESM over CJS in which case you will probably have to do more configuration to get a possibly working result...

Comment: Please send a GitHub issue