# ES6 import not working correctly in next.js application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm working on a tiny `next.js` project, but the issue that i'm facing is that `ES6 module import` only works in `React components`.The 2 following code are some Database configurations that are used in routes inside `API folder`.
The code below is the one that doesn't work using `ES6 modules`
[image: Code with ES6 module system]

Here is the code that works fine with `common js`
[image: Code using common JS]

Also when i use the debugger, with the code using ES6 modules, i cannot capture values form imported modules and i only capture values when using common js.

I've tried to solve the problem with this github issue : [Support ES module in next.config.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9607) but id did not help.
Have any idea?

Comment: Please show us how you are importing this module.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 imports does not working because this is server side rendering.

I advice you to use requirejs.

But if you wanna use ES6 imports in NodeJS it will be possible in new vesions, now it is an experimental feature ([you can read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules/37132668#37132668))

Try solution: update to the latest version on NodeJS