# How to update project when a dependency switches to pure ESM

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, node-fetch, es6-modules

We are developing a project that uses commonjs. When `node-fetch` is updated to v3.x, jest complains that:

```js
import fetch, { RequestInfo, RequestInit, Response } from 'node-fetch';
```

```sh
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

`npm run build` succeeds.

If I use `node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest` instead of `jest`, I get:

```sh
Must use import to load ES Module
```

I did some reading, it appears that we need to migrate our project to be an ESM as well. But it does not appear to be easy.

So the question is: when a dependency becomes pure ESM, how do we handle that in our code?

FYI, our project is: https://gitlab.com/tezgraph/tezgraph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js plans to support import/export ES6 (ECMAScript 2015) modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/node-js-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-ecmascript-2015-modules)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll see if that helps me