# Azure Functions: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions

I couldn't find a recent question talking about this so I decided to create a new one.

I'm building some azure functions with Typescript and I'm getting:

`import { Entity, BaseEntity, PrimaryColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from "typeorm";`
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

This is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when importing ECMAScript 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the 2 fixes you need to do to resolve the syntax error

1. Change `.js` files to `.cjs`
2. Also add `"type"` : `"Module"` to package.json

Also check the related [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37132668) threads and [Documentation](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/cannot+use+import+statement+outside+a+module+typescript).

Comment: Thanks! That worked! However, I also had to change  *.ts files to *.cts in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places to check and align:

1. `tsconfig.json`
2. `package.json`

`tsconfig.json` controls what Typescript compiler emits and how it resolves modules   **compilation-time**.
Important options in `tsconfig` are:

- ([module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module)) controls emission.
- ([moduleResolution option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution)) controls resolution.

`package.json`, in turn, controls how Nodejs resolves modules at **run-time**.
Important option is `type`. Of omitted `commonjs` is implied.

**You want both to be aligned.**

If you want classic go for:

```
//in package.json
"type": "commonjs",

//in tsconfig.json
"module": "CommonJS",
"moduleResolution": "node",
```

If you want futuristic, more readable, and backward-compatible to CommonJs output, use the following for ES modules:

```
//in package.json
"type": "module",

//in tsconfig.json
"module": "NodeNext",
"moduleResolution": "nodenext",
```