# Node.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected token import while running on node 6.10.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am running node version 6.10.2 I am trying to run this peice of code

```
import * as events from "events"
class MyClass extends events.EventEmitter {
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    compute(){
        return this.x * this.y;
    }
}
var vow = new MyClass(2,3);
vow.compute();
```

I am getting this error, How can I make it run?

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES2015 "import" not working in node v6.0.0 with with --harmony\_modules option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901147/es2015-import-not-working-in-node-v6-0-0-with-with-harmony-modules-option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodejs version 6.*.* do not support `import` and `export`. It cover 96% of es6.

So, you have to use `babel` to covert your es6 code to es5 version if you like to use Nodejs 6.

[take a look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901147/es2015-import-not-working-in-node-v6-0-0-with-with-harmony-modules-option)

Comment: I tried switching to node 7.9.0 but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Yeah, still exists in 8.3 version.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about it but i think node 6.x doesn't handle  `import` so you either need a transpiler like babel which will convert your es6 code into es5, you can use `require` instead of import or upgrade to node 7.x which should support `import` style. (You can use nvm to have many versions of node on your computer).

Comment: I tried switching to node 7.9.0 but I am still getting the same error