# How to use "import" in nodejs v6.11.3

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I want to use "import" in nodejs + express app.

I know that nodejs v6 support es6.

But I can't use "import" in my nodejs app.

Node give me This message. => SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

What can i do for es6.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901147/es2015-import-not-working-in-node-v6-0-0-with-with-harmony-modules-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js 6 does not support ESModules, only CommonJS modules. You can still use ESmodules but you will need to install [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and transpile your code.

Comment: Hi [fernando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7643589/fernando-poumi%c3%a1n),
Could you pls explain a bit more on detail how can Babel be used? I'm a javascript novice, and I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: if you are using node < 8.5 you can't.

If you want to use ES modules, either use a [newer version of node](http://2ality.com/2017/09/native-esm-node.html) or use Babel or a library like [@std/esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@std/esm).